# Missing layout / colors in web application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, css

I faced a issue that I have two sharepoint servers in one farm. I use NLB to balance the traffic to and from both servers.
I have web application which runs perfect for users however if I run the same web aplication locally on one of the server looks like some of the layouts elements are missing like background colors etc. On the other server everything seems fine.

Where I did wrong what can casue this kind of problem?

P.S.

The Web Application is custom soulution that has been deployed to SharePoint as *.WSP and it runs in 2010 mode.

Answer (score 1):

If the WSP contains these layout items that are missing, make sure the solution was successfully deployed to both servers. Also make sure all of these layout files (if they're in Style Library for example) are Published on both servers.

If there are some layout files outside the WSP that are located in 14 hive's _layouts folder, make sure all files are copied to both servers.

Comment: I have just checked and the soultion has been deployed corectlly on both servers with Style Library items too in 14 hive's

Comment: Any other ideas what casue the issue ?